# Cryptography Padding is invalid and cannot be removed occurs on ScryptoStream.close

Tags: vb.net, cryptography

I found and modified the code a bit but i'm having trouble with the error message "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

I encode on website A and decrypt on website B.  The thing is that this works most of the time but i get the error occasionally.  I'd was wondering if anyone can see what i've done wrong.  The padding.mode is PKCS7 on both the encrypting and decrypting sites.  I believe i have the CryptoStream correct in that it should close the stream before the encoding takes place but I don't pretend to have a good understanding of what i'm doing.  Here is the code.

```
Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal inText As String) As String
        Dim bytesBuff As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inText)
        Dim mKey As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EncodeDecodeKey")
        Using aes__1 As Aes = Aes.Create()
            Dim crypto As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(mKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})
            aes__1.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32)
            aes__1.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16)
            aes__1.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7  
            Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
                Using cStream As New CryptoStream(mStream, aes__1.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length)
                    cStream.Close()
                End Using
                inText = Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray())
            End Using
        End Using

        'encode for use with query string
        Return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inText)
    End Function

 Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal cryptTxt As String) As String
        Dim mKey As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EncodeDecodeKey")
        cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace(" ", "+")
        cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace("-", "+")
        cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace("_", "/")
        cryptTxt = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(cryptTxt)
        Dim bytesBuff As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptTxt)
        Using aes__1 As Aes = Aes.Create()
            Dim crypto As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(mKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, &H76})
            aes__1.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32)
            aes__1.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16)
            aes__1.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7  
            Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
                Using cStream As New CryptoStream(mStream, aes__1.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length)
                    cStream.Close()
                End Using
                cryptTxt = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(mStream.ToArray())
            End Using
        End Using
        Return cryptTxt
    End Function
```

On the decrypt the error message says i'm getting the error on line cStream.Close().  Again, this is working most of the time.

Thank you

Comment: The lines like `cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace(" ", "+")` look suspicious to me.

Comment: During encryption, the ciphertext is first Base64 and then Url encoded. During decryption, the ciphertext should therefore first be Url and then Base64 decoded. However, instead of the Url decoding, 3 replace calls are made followed by a Html decoding. Why?